# Is address.call(abi.encodeWithSignature(.....)) the best function to call functions of other smart contracts for with least gas fee consumption?

Tags: solidity

I am quite new to solidity coding. I am trying to find out the best way to call complex functions like `swap` from `1Inch exchange` smart contract from my smart contract which can execute the function by consuming the least possible `Eth Gas`. I dont think I can use `delegatecall()` directly. So, does this mean, the next best possible solution is to use the `call()` function like - `address.call((abi.encodeWithSignature(.....))` ?? I would like to know the best option out there which I can implement in my smart contract.

I will be executing a series of functions from different smart contracts such as `1Inch`, `Uniswap`, `Curve`, etc. Whats the best way to execute these functions which can reduce the `eth gas` consumption?

Can anyone guide me on this?

Regards,
Harish

Comment: If you know for sure that the function is implemented in that other contract, then you'd be better off calling it like you'd "normally" do.

Comment: @goodvibration You mean, you the normal approach like `address.approve(...)`, `address.swap(....)` instead of using the `call()` feature like `address.call((abi.encodeWithSignature(.....))`? Yes, those functions are present in the `1inch` contract.

Comment: So there's no reason for you to call them dynamically (i.e., using `encodeWithSignature`). If anything, it would just add to the gas cost. This type of calling is designated primarily in order to allow for a "try/catch" kind of execution in Solidity.